Can i dynamicaly set the session timeout per session?
I want to develop a keep me logged in today button for my login system.
I want to do this without the use of cookies if possible.
My first instinct was to change the session timeout based on this field.
Is this possible in CF11 or is this not possible?
In coldfusion i have tried to set the timeout of the session using:
getPageContext().getRequest().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
But if i set this at the login page it gets reset by the first other request.
If i do no requests after the login page i notice that the session ends but really OnSessionEnd doesn't get called but after 30 seconds the session is actually reset and OnSessionStart gets called while the session id stays the same as the one that should have expired.

One approach would be to put a target attribute on the button.  The target would be a 1 pixel by 1 pixel iFrame.  That iFrame would contain a self refreshing web page which would keep the session alive.
Since your question specifies "logged in today", you would have to write some code to ensure that it's still today.

You should never allow the user to specify the session timeout. When they can, they will increase it to as much as possible. For compliance reasons, you should set a global default for the entire application, affecting all users. Generally speaking, I've always defaulted to 20 minutes. If your application processes payments, there are more strict requirements.
OWASP Session Timeout Cheatsheet

Both the idle and absolute timeout values are highly dependent on how critical the web application and its data are. Common idle timeouts ranges are 2-5 minutes for high-value applications and 15-30 minutes for low risk applications. Absolute timeouts depend on how long a user usually uses the application. If the application is intended to be used by an office worker for a full day, an appropriate absolute timeout range could be between 4 and 8 hours.

PCI DSS v4.01 Requirements

8.2.8 If a user session has been idle for more than 15 minutes, the user is required to re-authenticate to re-activate the terminal or session.

